# Error when trying to input in Python Console

Tags: python, input

When I put

```
input('Enter your name please: ')
```

In the console, no dialogue box comes up just a >? where I type a word, then this happens.
https://imgur.com/lQDIutR

Sorry if this is obvious, I was part-way through learning C++, then switched to this, and it feels so different and alien, I get lost quite easily.

Edit: I am using the IDE PyCharm.

Comment: What is your line 1 content?

Comment: a = input('Enter your name please: ')

Comment: Sorry but I cannot produce your error...

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @Theroarx see my answer, It's probably because you're using python 2.7.

Comment: You are using Python 2, where you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Better yet, use Python 3

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in python 2.7, that's the reason you're seeing the error.

So here is the detail:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input('Enter your name please: ')
Enter your name please: hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

However, if you make sure to quote your input while typing, this works.

```
>>> input('Enter your name please: ')
Enter your name please: "My name is" 
'My name is'
>>>
```

This is the same console and now it works fine. This is the expected behaviour of python2. However if you do the same in the python3, it works fine.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input('Enter your name please: ')
Enter your name please: hi
'hi'
>>>
```

You don't need to quote the string input in python3. So you need to quote your string in your input response.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` so that what you input does not get evaluated as Python expression.

```
>>> input('Enter your name please: ')
Enter your name please: hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
>>> raw_input('Enter your name please: ')
Enter your name please: hi
'hi'
>>>
```